# How to redirect in nanoc

Tags: apache, nanoc

I am new to nanoc and I just setup by blog.

All my posts are under `/blog/post/Month/Post_name.html`, but every time I visit `/post/`, it shows me the Apache file list view.

Rather I want `/blog/post/*` to redirect to `/blog/` (which contains a list of all blog posts), but when accessed the `/blog/post/Month/Post_name.html`, it should show right.

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about Apache, not so much about nanoc.

In your configuration file, make sure that the `Options` does not include `Indexes`. This will turn off directory listings.

For redirection, you can use `mod_alias`. Take a look at the [documentation for redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Answer (score 3):

*Arjan van der Gaag* has a really nice solution for redirects like this.  According to [his `nanoc-template` wiki on that topic](https://github.com/avdgaag/nanoc-template/wiki/Configure-HTTP-redirects), you'll only need to add some info to your `config.yaml`:

```
redirects:
  -
    from: /foo
    to: /bar
  -
    from: /baz
    to: /qux
```

Then configure your `htaccess` file to include these settings:

```
<% if @site.config[:redirects] %>
# Set up URL redirects<% @site.config[:redirects].each do |h| %>
Redirect 301 <%= h[:from] %> <%= h[:to] %>
<% end %><% end %>
```

(Confer https://github.com/avdgaag/nanoc-template/blob/master/content/htaccess.txt)

The result will look like this:

```
Redirect 301 /foo /bar
Redirect 301 /baz /quz
```

A `301` ("Moved Permanently") will be too harsh in this case, though:  **you'll want a 303 redirect ("See other").**